# manipulate & modify exited code

Tags: bash, shell-script, docker

Currently i am running a automated test commands which somehow exits with 1 and i wanted it to modify with 0

```
exec wait-for --timeout "${WAIT_FOR_TIMEOUT:-10}" $WAIT_FOR_HOSTS -- \
nightwatch
```

i tried with

```
 #if grep succeeds (code 0) then FAILED was found, success it
if [[ $? = 1 ]]; then
  exit 0

fi
```

And it still didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec wait-for` will *replace* the shell process with the `wait-for` command, and nothing that comes after it will ever be executed.

you should drop the `exec` from before `wait-for`:

```
wait-for ...
if [[ $? = 1 ]]; then ...
```

or, even better:

```
wait-for ... || exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also use:

```
wait-for ... || true
```